# Buck Controller ICs: Does the rated input voltage range limit the buck circuit supply voltage?

Tags: buck, control

All of the buck controllers I found on the internet (e.g.; [LM5141](http://www.ti.com/product/lm5141)) assume that there will be a single input supply voltage in my circuit, and that voltage will be both supplying the IC and the buck controller circuit.

However, I want to supply the IC from a separate voltage source, and supply the buck circuit with a higher voltage (higher than the maximum allowed input voltage of the IC) as seen in the schematics below.

The input voltage of the power

[image: Simple Schematics]

My basic electronics knowledge says that this circuit is feasible since the IC won't see/feel the high voltage (e.g.: the 400V). Is there anything that may go wrong in a circuit like this?

Comment: In order to turn MH on, H must be at least 400V. That said, you could use a separate driver which could handle 400V.

Comment: The key point (implied but maybe not stated outright in the answers given) is that when MH is on the SW pin is taken to 400V AND the gate of MH must be avove 400V to suypply Vgs drive for MH. The control IC must be able to withstand the 400V and to provide 400V + Vgs drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are switcher ICs that expect you to provide the switches externally.  This is sometimes for the reason you state, which is to allow for a higher input voltage than the IC can handle.  Sometimes it is to allow for higher current than can reasonably pass thru a IC.  Unfortunately for you, the IC you show is intended for the latter case.

Note that the H output of the IC in your schematic actually needs to go higher than the 400 V input.  It is driving the gate of a N channel FET.  Your theory of the IC not seeing the high voltage is therefore incorrect.  It should also be obvious that the SW pin will see the high voltage.

You need to actually **read the datasheet**.  Right on page 1 is shows a typical schematic.  Even though the switches are external to the IC, clearly the IC has to handle the input voltage on several different pins.  Note the charge pump to make the extra high voltage for the driving the top FET.

Answer (score 1):

Controllers with built-in switches (e.g. [MP2467](http://www.monolithicpower.com/DesktopModules/DocumentManage/API/Document/getDocument?id=311), [LM2576](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf)) use the input voltage as both power input and controller circuitry input.

One *(and not the only)* exception is [MC34063](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC34063A-D.PDF). It is a controller with built-in transistor but it allows the designer to use separate supplies for controller and power inputs. It also allows using an external switch for e.g. higher current applications.

Note that the switch is in series with the power input, therefore a bootstrap circuitry may be needed to drive it (MH in your case).